# remove duplicate value existing object from multidimensional array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my javascript array:

```
 [{
     "id": "44",
     "name": "chathura"
 }, {
     "id": "45",
     "name": "gayan"
 }, {
     "id": "48",
     "name": "sunimal"
 }, {
     "id": "47",
     "name": "chathura"
 }, {
     "id": "20",
     "name": "yasith"
 }, {
     "id": "21",
     "name": "thisaru"
 }, {
     "id": "42",
     "name": "insaf"
 }, {
     "id": "63",
     "name": "sunimal"
 }, {
     "id": "78",
     "name": "yasith"
 }, {
     "id": "36",
     "name": "thisaru"
 }]
```

I want to remove duplicate name existing object element from this array and get the following:

```
[{
    "id": "47",
    "name": "chathura"
}, {
    "id": "45",
    "name": "gayan"
}, {
    "id": "48",
    "name": "sunimal"
}, {
    "id ": "20",
    "name ": "yasith "
}, {
    "id ": "21 ",
    "name ": "thisaru"
}, {
    "id ": "42 ",
    "name ": "insaf"
}]
```

How can I remove duplicates?

Comment: which one do you remove, first or second instance? what have you tried so far

Comment: are you using any libraries like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)?

Comment: Honestly maybe you don't know how to do it, but at least try and in the remote case you find yourself lost ask again. Is a simple task buddy give it a try maybe you will learn something new!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the array and use a hash table to filter any IDs that have already been used:

```
function getUniqueNames(nameObjects) {
  var existingIds = { };

  return nameObjects
    .filter(function(nameObject) {
      var id = nameObject.id;
      var alreadyExists = existingIds[id];
      existingIds[id] = true;
      return alreadyExists;
    });
```

I'm not sure about your use case, but it might make sense in your case just to convert the data into a Map. Maps work similar to a hash table, and will map each name to its ID. They enforce uniqueness by design:

```
var names = nameObjects
  .reduce(function(map, nameObject) {
    map.set(nameObject.id, nameObject.name);
    return map;
  }, new Map());

// Look up a name by ID
names.get(47);

// Do something for every name
names.forEach(function(name, key) {
  console.info(name, 'has ID', key);
});
```

Maps are ES6 and you may need a [polyfill](http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/introducing-smap-dot-js/) for some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this worked solution, using **[push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)** method :

**JS :**

```
var arr = {};
for ( var i=0; i < x.length; i++ )
    arr[x[i]['name']] = x[i];

var result = new Array();
for ( var key in arr )
    result.push(arr[key]);
```

That will return an array of objects `result` that contain a non duplicated objects.

**Result :**

```
[{
    "id": "47",
    "name": "chathura"
}, {
    "id": "45",
    "name": "gayan"
}, {
    "id": "48",
    "name": "sunimal"
}, {
    "id ": "20",
    "name ": "yasith "
}, {
    "id ": "21 ",
    "name ": "thisaru"
}, {
    "id ": "42 ",
    "name ": "insaf"
}]
```

Hope this will help.